# Is there a reason my questions do not get answered on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I often come here for help on issues, and I occasionally ask my own questions (especially with SSRS). Have I upset the smart people and been blacklisted on this site or do I just have the most difficult questions that no one can answer?

My [most recent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64327502/ssrs-subreport-unable-to-pass-multiple-value-pass-multiple-value-parameter-to-th) post did have someone ask if I could post the file that is giving me problems, but that is the only response I have seen on my last few questions.

Comment: Of your 10 questions, you've marked 50% as answered. Sounds like a fairly good ratio to me. Perhaps the ones that are unanswered require more clarity. By the way - this belongs on [meta].

Comment: I mark answers correct if they fix my issue. I try to be as clear as possible, but please let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: You say that's the one response you've had on your last few questions, but your [question before last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62310544/import-an-image-into-ssrs-report) (not including this one, as it'll be deleted/migrated) is marked as answered.

Comment: No one on here helped me with that. I figured it out with a coworker a month after posting it. So I answered the question and marked it correct future people.

Comment: Maybe just not many people currently answering in that tag? Don't see much activity on the front page of it currently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reporting-services

Comment: detailed, reproducible programming questions receive answers within minutes. is it easy for anyone to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Looks like basically for SSRS questions unless Alan Schofield answers it you are out of luck.  https://stackoverflow.com/tags/reporting-services/topusers (looking at top answerers in the last 30 days) - I would guess that chances are most of the ones answered by other people were really SQL ones

Comment: @toolic I think that can only be said to be true for popular tags

Comment: I guess they could reproduce it if they have a subreport with a parameter accepting multiple values and the passing them to the main report.

Comment: SSRS questions can be really difficult to answer, from my experience. They often lack enough information to answer, or are very difficult to replicate the "problem" that is being described, as it requires creating a copy of the report, along with sample data. Often, as well I feel like the only way to answer them is with a tutorial, and (honestly) I'm rarely interested in writing such long answers unless the question really engages me.

Comment: I do, at times, think that SSRS questions don't really below on Stack Overflow as well. Often the problems aren't programming related, but more about how to achieve some kind of display format; they're more akin to "How do I present my data like this in Excel?" which are often better off asked on [su], not [so].

Comment: ssrs questions should be asked in dba.

Comment: Only 1 in 4 odds to get an answer in [ssrs] within a month.  Nobody earns any rep in that tag, Alan is the last of the Mohicans, got 12 votes on 37 posts last month.  Chicken and egg, unfortunately that doesn't inspire SO users often enough to think "maybe I ought to help out more".  Looks to me you can, pay it forward.

Comment: See [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/289905).

Answer (score 15):

You have 9 questions on Stack Overflow. You've accepted an answer on 5 of them, one has 3 answers, another one has 2 answers (one of which is upvoted), one has a self-answer, and only your most recent one hasn't been answered yet.

Unless there are deleted questions that I can't see, "my questions don't get answered" seems like a bit of an exaggeration TBH, given that all but one of your non-deleted questions have an answer (or even multiple answers).

Comment: As I stated above, my last question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62310544/import-an-image-into-ssrs-report)  was answered by me after a month of no one on here saying anything. 
I think the one previous to that [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61940481/ssrs-report-filtering-based-on-a-parameter) was also answered by me. I asked it on here because I was up against a deadline and was hoping someone could easily see what I could not.

Comment: @user3691608 Alright, but 7 out of 9 is still 78%. I don't see where you're getting the idea that people are ignoring all of your questions - it's simply not true (unless you have a lot of deleted questions that I can't see).

Comment: I was simply wondering why my last few questions have not even been attempted after days. I thought I either upset people and they don't want to answer my questions or do I just have the hard ones that no one knows. Just wondering if there was something I was doing wrong in my posts.

Comment: @user3691608 Sometimes it takes a little while to get answers - there are lots of questions on Stack Overflow per day.

Comment: @user3691608 - That user who wanted a sample file is still waiting for that file.  That was 2 days ago.

Comment: Can you attach a file like that on this site? I tried but could not find an attach button.

Comment: @user3691608: Couldn't [the process of MRCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) cut it down to the essential part so it can be copied directly into the post?